# AngularJS - ng-init not working with $resource and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Good afternoon everybody, since I haven't found any solution to my problem, 
I'm here =X Here's the deal: I'm trying to initilize a ng-model using the ng-init calling a function, but in this function im using a custom $resource method. Now comes the problem, ng-init does not wait the promise to be resolved to assign the value to the model, it passes right over it and since the promise isn't resolved is assigns undefined to it. Here are the codes:

Html with inputs and ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-form="itemsForm" ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td>
                  <div class="has-feedback"
                    ng-class="{
                        'has-error': itemsForm.product.$invalid && itemsForm.product.$dirty,
                      'has-success': itemsForm.product.$valid   && itemsForm.product.$touched
                    }">
                    <input type="text" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-no-results="noResultsProduct" required name="product" placeholder="Digite o codigo ou Descrição" class="form-control input-sm" id="product" typeahead-on-select="item.prod_code = product.codigo; updateFields(product)" ng-model="product" ng-init="product=item.prod_code; product=find_product(item.prod_code)" uib-typeahead="product as (product.descricao + ' - ' + product.codigo) for product in getProducts($viewValue) | orderBy:'descricao' | limitTo:15"/>
                    <p class="help-block" ng-messages="itemsForm.product.$error">
                      <span ng-message="required">Produto não informado.</span>
                      <span ng-if="noResultsProduct">Nenhum Produto encontrada.</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </td>
```

Function that ng-init calls:

```
$scope.find_product = function(product) {
  if (product != null){
    console.log("Started");
    ProductService.find_by($scope.company_id,product).$promise.then(function(data) {
      console.log(data.products);
      return data.products;
    });
    console.log("Finished");
  }
}
```

Service function:

angular.module("application").service('ProductService',['$resource','$http', function($resource,$http){

```
this.products = function(company_id, search_filter){
  var services_product = $resource('/services_product/all',
                           {},
                           { "all": { "method": "POST" }});
  return services_product.all({"company_id": company_id, "search_filter": search_filter});
};

this.find_by = function(company_id, search_filter){
  var services_product = $resource('/services_product/find_by',
                           {},
                           { "find_by": { "method": "POST" }});
  return services_product.find_by({"company_id": company_id, "search_filter": search_filter});
};
```

}
]);

Whats is being printed in the console:

```
Started
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:125 Finished
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:120 Started
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:125 Finished
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:120 Started
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:125 Finished
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:120 Started
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:125 Finished
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:120 Started
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:125 Finished
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:122 Object {filial: "01  ", codigo: "1000028        ", descricao: "57 - PRENSA CABO STECK BSP- 1/2 - COD.                                          ", tipo: "MP", unidade: "PC"…}
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:122 Object {filial: "01  ", codigo: "1000028        ", descricao: "57 - PRENSA CABO STECK BSP- 1/2 - COD.                                          ", tipo: "MP", unidade: "PC"…}
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:122 Object {filial: "01  ", codigo: "1000022        ", descricao: "61 - VIGA PINUS 2 POL X 1 POL - 4M                                              ", tipo: "EM", unidade: "PC"…}
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:122 Object {filial: "01  ", codigo: "10000105       ", descricao: "61 - TABUA PINUS 3 POL X 20MM - 4000MM                                          ", tipo: "EM", unidade: "PC"…}
document_nfe_reception_controller.js?body=1:122 Object {filial: "01  ", codigo: "1000033        ", descricao: "CABO CONTROLE VEIAS NUMER.CL5 6X1,5 MM  1 KV                                    ", tipo: "MP", unidade: "MT"…}
```

I'm doing with 5 items, As you can see, he is only getting the data after everything executed. Appreciate any help =))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning "data.products" in promise callback, you should assign data.products to item.product.

```
$scope.find_product = function(item) {
    if (product != null){
        console.log("Started");
        ProductService.find_by($scope.company_id,item.prod_id).$promise.then(function(data) {
            console.log(data.products);
            item.product = data.products;
        });
        console.log("Finished");
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-no-results="noResultsProduct" required name="product" placeholder="Digite o codigo ou Descrição" class="form-control input-sm" id="product" typeahead-on-select="item.prod_code = product.codigo; updateFields(product)" ng-model="item.product" ng-init="find_product(item)" uib-typeahead="product as (product.descricao + ' - ' + product.codigo) for product in getProducts($viewValue) | orderBy:'descricao' | limitTo:15"/>
```

Comment: Already tried, it didnt work, and even if it did work it would assign the same value for all items inside ng-repeat...

Comment: Yes, it will assign the same value for all the items in ng-repeat because we have same variable (product) in ng-model for every item.

Comment: Thats why im using return, for every item that calls ng-init, it will return the value to THAT item that called the function..

Comment: I edited the answer. Now ng-model="item.product" and ng-init="find_product(item)". Also instead of item.prod_id, I m passing the item object in the find_product method and assigning data.products to item.product.